# Backing up and restoring MySQL db to new OS MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

This may be basic question but I am pretty new to MySQL and server setup. I am going to install a different os where I will have LAMP setup, earlier I installed on Rasbian Jessie each of those manually.

How do I backup and restore to a different server.

Answer (score 0):

Just install MySQL server and you will able to connect to DB from any environment. Also you can connect to remote database if you have some host for example

Comment: Can you direct me to some documentation that shows how to connect my sql set up on different machine or remote on Internet .